# Problemas con la libreria segyio

Tags: python

Estoy buscando inspeccionar una sísmica en python (con la librería segyio) y estoy presentando este error. Si alguien ha trabajado con esta libreria y sabe como solucionarlo lo agradecería muchísimo!

> "Invalid dimensions, ilines (528) * xlines (619) * offsets (1) should match the number of traces (327235)"